# Moment Js Date Comparison

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

I want to check if the **current date** is valid in between the dates starting from 07-11-2017 till 05-01-2018 using **moment.js**.

**Any help??** How to do it?

I'm having the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

class Dates extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dateNow: moment(),
      availability:''
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let startdate = moment("17-11-2017");
    let enddate = moment("05-01-2018");

    this.setState({
      availability: 'Yes'
    });
  }
  render() {
    return(
       <div>
         <div>{this.state.dateNow}</div>
         <table>
           <tr>
             <td>Available from 7th November,2017 to 5th January,2018?</td> 
             <td>{this.state.availability}</td>
           </tr>
          </table>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Dates;
```

Comment: check this: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ajit

Comment: Subhojit please check the answers before marking as bestanswer visit the https://momentjs.com/ and type the answer in console.log the date you mentioned in the question must return true but in elumalai_kp it is returning false so it is an invalid answer his approach is correct but answer is incorrect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `isBetween` to check availability like

`moment('22-11-2017').isBetween('17-11-2017', '05-01-2018');`

Method returns `true` if condition is true else `false`.

Comment: it will return invalid in the current format as you have to first change the strings to valid moment objects and it is returning false as of now you can check in https://momentjs.com/ after you format it correctly in the date format it will return true value.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. There's no use of that date variable which I had given. As I mentioned the current date, you needed to put this.state.dateNow instead of date. Look I had set dateNow: moment() to get the current date.

Answer (score 2):

first convert it into valid date objects

```
let date  = moment("22-11-2017", "DD-MM-YYYY")
let startdate = moment("17-11-2017","DD-MM-YYYY");
let enddate = moment("05-01-2018","DD-MM-YYYY");
```

then convert the dates in the date format
using

```
var a = date.toDate();b= startdate.toDate(),c=enddate.toDate();
```

and then use a simple if conditions

```
 if (a.getTime() >=b.getTime() && a.getTime() <=c.getTime())
     console.log('do your stuff')
    else 
    console.log('sorry timeout')
```

you can also use this

```
date.isBetween(startdate,enddate)
```

Comment: your moment object as of now returns invalid date

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. There's no use of that date variable which I had mentioned. As I also had mentioned the **current date**, you needed to put **this.state.dateNow** instead of date. Look I had set dateNow: moment() to get the current date. But you have also put the same as **elumalai_kp**.. it's also **22-11-2017** you have put to compare. Elumalai_kp was the first to answer & his approach was right like yours, so I marked his one at first. @Sagar